# reshape imagen dividing the size

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have an image with the following dimensions: (339,339,3) and i need to convert to (113,113,3).

I tried the following:

```
new_image = process_img.reshape(process_img.shape[0]/3*process_img.shape[1]/3*process_img.shape[2]/3)
```

the error is the following:
could not broadcast input array from shape (966,339,3) into shape (322,113,3)

but didnt work, anyone can help me?

Comment: `numpy` `reshape` does not change the total number of elements.

Comment: what function need for this case?

Comment: The image modules (`cv2` or whatever) have `resize` method(s).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `reshape` when the total sum of elements is different.

a good usage of `reshape` might be:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
a.reshape((2,2))
```

in total there are still 4 elements.

in order to remove elements, there must be some logic as to how exactly you wish to remove said elements